# Regex: at-least one text value must present

Tags: validation-rule

I have built out a formula field to ensure that there is at least one letter added into a text field in order to save it.  It is not erroring out when a letter is missing.

Please see below:

```
AND( $Profile.Name <> "Sales", 
OR( 
RecordType.Name = "New Business", 
RecordType.Name = "Discounts", 
RecordType.Name = "Upsell" ), 

AND( 
OR( 
ISBLANK(Comment_Happy__c))), 
NOT(REGEX(Comment_Happy__c,".*[a-zA-Z].*")) )
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I updated the question heading to make it more context sensitive and added my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To find the text with at-least one text value will be as follows:

```
REGEX( Comment_Happy__c , "(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*")
```

You can merge the above statement into your validation rule properly, hopefully it will be like this:

```
AND( $Profile.Name <> "Sales", 
OR( 
RecordType.Name = "New Business", 
RecordType.Name = "Discounts", 
RecordType.Name = "Upsell" ), 

AND( 
OR( 
ISBLANK(Comment_Happy__c))), 
NOT( REGEX( Comment_Happy__c , "(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*")) )
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu Boral - if I type in "1) and space" and hit save, it saves and doesn't throw an error still.

Comment: I have checked the Regex part at my DE it is perfectly working. first check the regex part and then add profile and recordtype checks into validation rule

Comment: check `NOT(REGEX( Comment_Happy__c , "(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*"))` is working

Comment: I think that it works, but I get an error on Save that the field is needed.